# CSS max-height does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to make a container automatically expand. To do so I want to use max-height property. This is my html structure

```
<div class='palm-row first' style="max-height:200px">
     <div class="palm-row-wrapper">
           <div class="textfield-group" x-mojo-focus-highlight="true"
                style="max-height:200px">
               <div class="title">  
                <div class="truncating-text" id="nameField" class="recipient-picker"
                 x-mojo-element="TextField" style="max-height:200px"></div>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.recipient-picker{
    overflow:hidden; 
    margin-right:0px;
    max-width:300px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

I want the textfield to expand in height. However it does not work settings max-height. The container do not change height. However when I set min-height, the correct height is applied.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Any other ideas?

Comment: max-height is a limit. "do no go past this size". It does not affect the height of an element, UNLESS that element tries to grow larger than the height limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max-height` sets the **maximum** height of an element if it tries to grow past that size. `min-height` sets the **minimum** height of an element if it tries to grow below that size. In your case, the default textfield height is less than your specified `min-height`, so the browser will increase it's height so that the `min-height` constraint is satisfied.

So what's the problem with just using `min-height` if it works?

Comment: the problem is  that I want to use max height because I want the textfield to grow if the content does not fit into it. But max height has no effect.the textfield is growing but the structure around the textfield does not change. So the textfield is kind of growing underneeth the wrapper and row